# Jersey error in my restful web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I am using Jetty server, Jersey2 and Java Spring for my web RESTFUL  server. When I started my server using the following POM file, it will throw some kind of Jar conflict error. But I can't figure out which jar I am using that conflicts with the Jersey2. Could someone help me out?

Here is my pom file and exceptions.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
        <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
        <artifactId>wink-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
        <artifactId>wink-json4j-provider</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
        <artifactId>wink-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.pinyin4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>pinyin4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>       
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>Pingplusplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>pingpp-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.qiniu</groupId>
        <artifactId>qiniu-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>[7.0.0, 7.0.99]</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

when i started my server,it will show this throwalbe to me.

```
[WARNING] Error for /xiugr-server-service/restful/qiniu/video/getTokenjava.lang.AbstractMethodError:
javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:289)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1448)
at com.kingdowin.xiugr.server.Filter.AuthorKeyFilter.doFilter(AuthorKeyFilter.java:29)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Show your `/xiugr-server-service/restful/qiniu/video/getToken`.

Comment: `@Path("qiniu")
public class QiniuResource {

    @Autowired
    QiniuService qiniuService;
    @GET
    @Path("{type}/getToken")
    @Produces("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    public Response getToken(@PathParam("type")String type) {
        Response response = new Response();
        TokenDTO tokenDTO = qiniuService.getToken(type);
        TokenResult tokenResult = new TokenResult(tokenDTO.getToken());
        response.setResult(tokenResult);
        response.setIErrorCode(ErrorCode.SUCCESS);
        return response;
    }
}`

Comment: All the response get the same error. I think it's nothing to do with any specific Resouce Class. It's caused by Jar conflict.